# Select particular text and format it(Bold, Italic and so on) using robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I have a text in a div tag "Robot Framework tutorial"

I want to select Robot text and mark it as bold as shown in the below image.

[image]

Comment: So, the question is how you can do it or something else?

Comment: How to do it? I have tried it but unable to highlight the text and format it as Bold

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: *** Setting ***
Library     Selenium2Library
Library     String

*** Test Cases ***
Get subselection
    ${string}=    Get Text    xpath=/html/div
    ${substring}=    Get Substring  ${string}   25  35

Comment: Please [edit]  your question. Code in the comment section is almost impossible to read.

Answer (score 0):

Robot framework has no direct support for doing what you want to do. What you'll have to do is write a javascript function that can find what you want and add a span around it so that you can associate a style with the span. You can then call that function via the [Execute Javascript](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Execute%20Javascript) keyword.